# SXA 1.6 CheckList filter Issue

Tags: sxa, content-search

We use 2 Checklist Filter to filter Search Result.

The problem we faced  is the second filter affect the first filter and that is required (by narrowing filter) but this doesn't happen when using the first filter and the second filter doesn't affect

Note: filtration of Search Result is working fine in both cases

Answer (score 1):

Play with `Collapse on selection` setting in the Control Properties dialog:

[image]

If this doesn't help then maybe simply your data is built that way that one of the facets are not narrowing the second one and the filtering is working but simply there is nothing to filter.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply it is working right

Comment: If the something is solving your problem than mark it as an answer. This helps others to find useful posts and answers that really solve problems.